# PHP only loads extension if apc.so is located in my www folder

Tags: linux, php, gentoo, extension

This is pretty strange situation I am getting.

I have installed apc (with `./configure` and `make`) on my LAMP gentoo with PHP 5.2.

To get apc loaded i need to place `apc.so` in my www php directory otherwise it just don't get loaded.

I don't even any idea of this, if you have even only tips please post an answer.

If you need the full series of command it's here: [Failed installing APC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/274261/failed-installing-apc)

Answer (score 1):

check the extensions_path variable in your php.ini. This defines where php will look for extensions.Gentoo might require you modify one of the include files

http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/php/php-upgrading.xml
http://www.reallylinux.com/docs/php.ini

Comment: just checked: `"./"` (don't know which is the absolute path for that, thansk for input anyway)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing for you to do would be to remove all of the work you've done by hand on your Gentoo system, and install Apache, PHP, and APC through the Gentoo way:  using Portage.